# GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); 1.0f screws the image up

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl

I recently started using LWJGL in my java programs for the graphics. I'm currently working on a simple game, which I make, to get better at this kind of programming. I ran into some trouble when adding textures to my 2D game.

To show my problem, I have made a simple program which shows one quad with a texture.
This is how the texture looks:

http://i1197.photobucket.com/albums/aa428/GWigWam/LWJGL%20problem/Test.png

However my program shows it like this:

http://i1197.photobucket.com/albums/aa428/GWigWam/LWJGL%20problem/showsme.png

You see the right and the bottom have some strange line hanging there. the shown picture is 100x100 from the top left to the little pixel right down.

The code used for drawing this is:

```
texture1.bind();
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
   GL11.glTexCoord2f(0f,0f);
   GL11.glVertex2f(100, 200);
   GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f,0f);
   GL11.glVertex2f(200, 200);
   GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f,1f);
   GL11.glVertex2f(200, 100);
   GL11.glTexCoord2f(0f,1f);
   GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100);
GL11.glEnd();
```

This code is called before drawing:

```
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    GL11.glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);
```

When I use

```
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.9f,0.9f);
```

so 0.9f instead of 1.0f the weird lines don't appear. But that's no real solution because I want to use the whole texture not 90% of it.

I hope I did not ask something which has been asked before, I really couldn't find I using google, it is however quite hard to think of the right search words.

Comment: You might have to set your texture repeat mode to clamp.

Comment: UV really run (0..1], which is really 0..1-(1/texwidth) if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed now, the WRAP_S wasn't the solution. It is **the size of the image** a 100x100 image shows this weird bug, but a 128x128 does not. 500x500 does not work 512x512 does.

Thanks to Nicol Bolas for trying to help, I would like to +rep, but I can't.
Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 4):

You should set your texture's wrap S and T modes to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. This is done with the [`glTexParameter`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexParameter) set of functions. Something like this:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Or the LWJGL equivalent to this.

You should call this when you're creating the texture (after your call to glTexImage2D), not when you're using it.

Also, don't forget to call it with `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` too.

Comment: GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); Might do the same, where exactly do I have to call it?

Comment: @GWigWam: "You should call this when you're creating the texture (after your call to glTexImage2D), not when you're using it."

Comment: texture1 = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("img/Test.png"));           GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);                                           It's quite hard to enter code into the reply thing... After this code Render() is called (That's the firs piece of code in the orrigional post. Did I place it wrongly? The problem isn't solved! It still looks ugly.

Comment: @GWigWam: "It's quite hard to enter code into the reply thing..." That's because this is not a forum. If you need to change your question, then you *change* it. In any case, I don't know what `TextureLoader.getTexture` does; is that your code or someone else's?

Comment: TextureLoader.getTexture saves a texture form a file (img/Test.png) in a Texture variable called texture1.